# TVC PID Controller how to adjust angle and thrust?

Tags: pid-controller, optimization, vector-control

Hi there I wanted to simulate a rocket landing like for example the falcon 9. I was able to write myself an simulation in which on every loop turn I adjust the angle and thrust. Now this is for school and we are supposed to use a PID-Controller. I think I understood the basic concept of a PID but in all the examples there were only one input and one output. Now I have two inputs do I build two PID-Controllers or is there another way? Also my Input is a speed vector how to I handle that in the PID-Controller. Any help would be cool.

Comment: Welcome to EESE, SebNik. So you are a high schooler? Did your teacher tell you to use a PID as a class project? If so try talking to him, because using (many) PID controllers to control a multi-input multi-output (MIMO) is not a simple task and there is no simple way to find how many PIDs to use or how to interconnect them to actually get a good result. PID is something "easy" for single-input single-output (SISO) linear systems. For a system like that it would be easier to use state-space control, but that might be very mathematical https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation

Comment: Yes I thought myself okay the State-Space Reprensation looks good okay thank a lot!